# Сравнение или "творительный падеж"? Нужно ли обособлять "как чётки"?

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

> На этот раз я была более чем подготовлена ко встрече с Италией –
>   теперь за плечами университетские курсы, отдельно по каждому периоду
>   истории Вечного города, и я **как чётки** перебрасывала картинки
>   одного знаменитого памятника за другим…

Comment: Насколько я знаю,  обычные четки **перебирают** (бусинка  за бусинкой) , а **перебрасывают** ( или **крутят**),  как единое целое особые перекидные четки, модные у блатных.

Comment: Может, и картинки _перебирать_ лучше? Трудно понять, _куда_ и зачем их "перебрасывают" - по сети кому-то, между папками или ещё как-то. Бросается в глаза расхождение времён: прошлое и настоящее относятся к одному моменту (была подготовлена = теперь есть курсы). Можно _теперь... **были** курсы_.

Comment: Сашко, это стиль автора - "расхождение времён". А перебрасывала, должно быть, фотографии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...и я, **как чётки,** перебрасывала картинки одного знаменитого памятника за другим…

Это сравнение, а не обстоятельство: я перебрасывала картинки, как перебрасывают чётки.

Пример: На руке у нее всегда висела связка карточек со шведскими словами, которые она, даже гуляя, перебирала, **как четки**, и проверяла свои знания. [З. И. Воскресенская. Сердце матери (1963-1965)]

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написала так:
**На этот раз я была более чем подготовлена ко встрече с Италией – теперь за плечами университетские курсы, отдельно по каждому периоду истории Вечного города – и, как зерна чёток, перебрасывала картинки одного знаменитого памятника за другим…**

1. Выделила вставку (можно поставить и скобки вместо тире) и убрала "лишнее" я.
2. Изменила сравнительный оборот.

*Узоры ковров и рисунки цветов на кошме. Орнамент пиал и чайников. Он обретал их морщины и бороды, их выпуклые, с чернильным блеском глаза, уменье носить чалму и **перебрасывать зернышки четок.***
[А. Проханов. Стеклодув](https://books.google.ee/books?id=oRHzM_uFFkgC&pg=PT136&lpg=PT136&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=k_i_A7j8j2&sig=WsA1Kj-79leOScOJygfqyNmFkgw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2mPrporzaAhVQCuwKHQAcDWo4ChDoATAEegQIABBL#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false)